# How to align the words with the bars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have the following tikzpicture but, as you can see below, it doesn't align correctly - what did I do wrong?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    symbolic y coords = {Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web notification},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web notification)};
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS)};
  \addplot coordinates {(50,E-Mail)};
  \addplot coordinates {(52,Chat)};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: @leandriis Done (:

Comment: Does `\addplot coordinates {(68,Web notification) (22,SMS) (50,E-Mail) (52,Chat)};` give you the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are more satisfied with the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line = none,
    tickwidth = 0pt,
    symbolic y coords = {Chat,E-Mail,SMS,Web notification},
    nodes near coords,
    bar shift=0pt %<--------------- added
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(68,Web notification) };
  \addplot coordinates {(22,SMS) (50,E-Mail) (52,Chat)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you maybe also know why the bar length does not really correspond to the number? 22 should be about half of 50 but it is way less somehow.

Comment: @leonheess: With `xmin=0` the output should look at expected.

Comment: Do you by chance also know how to reduce the spacing between the bars?

Comment: @leonheess: Add `y=20pt` or any other length of your choice.

Comment: Sorry to bug you yet again: When having six `symbolic y coords` and bars only every other  `symbolic y coord` is shown - how can I make sure all are always visible?